# Intellij IDEA: Make refactor > Rename not select the whole word

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, rename

When I press my shortcut to rename a variable (precisely it's the "Main menu" > "Refactor" > "Rename..." shortcut), the **entire word is selected**.

Is it possible to change the behavior so that simply the refactoring is activated and the cursor stays in position (it already does, this is fine) and that I can directly add or remove a character?

Right now, if I have a variable "myVarible" and I put my cursor between "i" and "b" to add the "a", press the shortcut, and type an "a", my entire variable becomes an "a", as the entire word was selected by the shortcut.

In Eclipse this seems to be the default behavior already, and I liked it much better. How can I change this in Intellij?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can do this by going to Settings -> General -> Refactoring and just deselect "Preselect old name" or just type Refactor in search box in settings so it will automatically go on above menu.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I searched for :) Thank you!

Comment: In the current version the option is under Settings -> Editor -> General in the sub-section Refactorings.

Comment: In the current version the option is under Settings -> Editor -> Code Editing in the sub-section Refactorings.

Answer (score 6):

From IntelliJ 2018.2.6, the checkbox to disable is still "Preselect old name".
That is located in :

```
"Settings" menu
-> "Editor" section
   -> "General" subsection 
   -> "Refactorings" part
```

You can also just enter "refactorings" in the search box to find it.

[image: disable preselect old name]

Answer (score 4):

## Origin answer

Aaaand it moved again!

It's probably the best to just search for `Refactorings` or `Preselect old name`, as it might move again in the future.

In my version `2020.1.2` it is under

> Settings -> Editor -> Code Editing -> Refactoring

[image]

## Update Version 2023(.1)

JetBrain can't decide where to put and how to name this feature.

Since my origin answer it was renamed to "Preselect current symbol name for Rename Refactoring" and it moved to:

> Settings -> Editor -> Code Editing

Answer (score 1):

It has changed name since the other answers, in `2021.2.3`, It's still under `Settings -> Editor -> Code Editing -> Refactorings` however it's now named `Preselect current symbol name for Rename refactoring`.